# How do I design a custom reusable view in IB and see the contents in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I would like to design a re-usable view in storyboard.

For example I might design a custom view that would be placed inside a prototype cell inside two different tables,  the main point is I design the layout for this view once and then reuse it multiple times.

1. This custom view
   will contain a "root" view, and various standard controls (ie 
   ImageView's Labels, etc) as subviews of the "root" view.
2. I would like to use auto layout to define the constraint
   relationships between these standard views and also their constraint
   relationships to the "root" view.
3. I would then like to reference this custom view in multiple places
   in my main storyboard **and actually see the sub-views when this
   custom view is placed inside my main storyboard.**

I have been trying out [this](http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2014/09/ios-creating-reusable-uiviews-with-storyboard-part-2/) approach, and while the view does show when I run the app, I still only see a blank view where I use it in the storyboard. **My goal is to also see the sub-views as I design the storyboard.**

Here is my custom subclass of UIView

```
@IBDesignable
class UserView: UIView {

  @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UserView!
  @IBOutlet weak var aLabel: UILabel!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("UserView", owner: self, options: nil)
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(self.contentView)
    superview?.addConstraint((NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)))
    superview?.addConstraint((NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)))
    superview?.addConstraint((NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)))
    superview?.addConstraint((NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)))
  }
}
```

I have created a simple UserView.xib file containing just a label, and 
set it's file owner to the UserView.swift file containing the class.
[image]
I add the view as a subview of another view by adding a UIView and then setting it's class to UserView, but I don't see the label in the storyboard.

[image]

When I run the app, I do see the custom view (with the label).

[image]

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: So its working fine for you, You can't see it in storyboard bro it will only be seen after you run.

Comment: you can add the view in prototype cell so you can view in design rather than making new xib.

Comment: @Imran, yes but the question is how do I see the contents of what I have placed in the storyboard.

Comment: @BankerMittal, yes but the idea is to use the same layout in multiple places.  forexample I might want to use the same view in different prototype cells for different tables.

Comment: ok i got your point but yes as Imran say you can not see it in storyboard.